# Can we rebuild node native module on Linux for win32 platform using node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp, electron-builder, node-ffi

I've created an electron application which uses two NodeJS native modules `node ref` and `node ffi`. The application is being developed on windows right now and the windows executable is generated with the help of **electron-builder**. This all works perfectly fine and the application is installed in windows properly. As both `ffi and ref` are native modules, I'm simply use **electron-rebuild** to rebuild them for platform win32 (I guess that internally uses `node-gyp`).

But the problem is, my CI/CD server is Ubuntu 16 and I need to generate the windows executable file there. If my application doesn't have node's native addons, it works fantastic but with native modules included, the exe file is generated but on launch it says **%1 is not a win32 application** and the reason for that is, the native deps are rebuilt for Linux platform instead of windows.

So I wanted to know is, is there any way to rebuild the node native modules on Linux machine for win32 platform or if its not possible then how can we use the pre-built `.node` file across the platforms.

Comment: Im havin the same problem rn bro 